# Weird glow in render

Tags: rendering, materials, lighting

[image]I've made a Yooka model from Yooka-Laylee as part of a college assignment, but I've noticed a weird glow either below the top lip or on top of the bottom lip. I'm currently using a Toon Shader and I've messed around with the Size and Smooth settings. It does the same thing just using a Diffuse shader. I've even tried positioning the light source, but it doesn't help. Any ideas? Also, what could I do to get rid of that green reflection from the eye? The cornea uses a glass shader and, again, I've tried messing with the properties but it's not helping.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide more info regarding your material setup. Can you edit your question to include images of your nodes and also share your blend file if possible.

Comment: I'm not using nodes; just the material's properties. I'm also using Cycles Render. I've uploaded a save.

Comment: Cycles materials are nodes. When you use the materials properties tab, it just creates the nodes in the node editor.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just meant I wasn't in the Node Editor adding my own custom nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The glow simply comes from a lamp you let inside the head, lighting up strongly everything inside and bleeding outside. Delete that lamp and you'll be fine.

[image]

Comment: D'oh. Nicely spotted. Thank you. Thought it was some setting that needed to be adjusted, but turns out it was a silly mistake on my part. No idea how that got in there lol.